# jQuery: Temporarily disable the click listener

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an app which handles a lot of jQuery events, and I need a way to differentiate simple clicks from text selections.

I'd like to disable all click events when I detect a text selection. Is this possible? I've thought of doing it like this:

```
// User presses mouse button
$(window).on('mousedown', function(){

    // User moves mouse while pressing mouse button => selection
    this.one('mousemove', function(){

        // Disable click listener temporarily
        $.fn.click = null;

    // User releases mouse button => end of selection
    }).on('mouseup', function(){

        // Stop mousemove event & restore click listener
        this.off('mousemove');
        $.fn.click = function(){};
    }); 
});
```

The code obviously won't work but serves to illustrate my goal. Does anyone know of a good way to achieve this?

Comment: Why do you want do disable the click listener? If so use `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: Because the click event will fire regardless of the user's intent, which may be to simply select text.

Comment: Why is there a click event set in the first place?

Comment: I have many click event handlers on different elements in the document, that's why I want to disable it once globally if the user selects text.

Comment: That's undoable, unless you keep track of all your click handlers and stop them when needed.

Comment: Ok, I hoped I could avoid micromanaging all the click events, but if it's not possible, then I'll just plunge into the code and add conditions. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Something as simple as setting a flag would work for your example.

```
var flag = true;
...
if(flag === true)
{
   --Click listener enabled code here--
}
else
{
   --Click listener disabled code here--
}
```

All you have to do is determine when to enable or disable the flag.

Answer (score 0):

Just use flag, like this:

```
var flag = 0;
// User presses mouse button
$(window).on('mousedown', function(){
    if (flag == 0) {
        // do some if click event enabled
    }
    // User moves mouse while pressing mouse button => selection
    this.one('mousemove', function(){
        // Disable click listener temporarily
        // $.fn.click = null;
        flag=1;
        // User releases mouse button => end of selection
    }).on('mouseup', function(){
        // Stop mousemove event & restore click listener
        // this.off('mousemove');
        // $.fn.click = function(){};
        flag = 0;
    }); 
});
```